# How to put variables from a string into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton

I'm making a project where I have a grid of JButtons and I want to be able to save which of those buttons are clicked into an array. I know how to get the coordinates for each button but am pretty clueless as to how I go about making an array and changing the coordinates stored inside whenever a JButton is clicked.
My code is as follows:

```
public ButtonGrid(int width, int length, String coords) {
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, length));
    grid = new JButton[width][length];
    state = new HashMap<JButton, String>();

    for (int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            final JButton nb = new JButton();
            nb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
            grid[x][y] = nb;
            state.put(grid[x][y], "blank");

            nb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Object source = e.getSource();
                    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
                            if (source == grid[i][j]) {
                                String coords = String.valueOf(grid[i][j]);
                                System.out.println(
                                        Stream.of(coords.split("\\D+")).limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (state.get(nb).equals("blank"))
                        mapButtonToColor(nb, "red");
                    else if (state.get(nb).equals("red"))
                        mapButtonToColor(nb, "blank");
                    setButtonColors();
                }
            });
            frame.add(grid[x][y]);
        }
    }

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: What attempts have you made to change your print statement to add to a list?

Comment: Also, `String.valueOf(grid[i][j]);` isn't only returning the coordinates... I assume you only want `i +"," +j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest you use inheritance

```
public class GridButton extends JButton {
    int x, y;
   // String state; // probably put this here instead 
    public GridButton(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    } 
}
```

Then, you'll want a list more than an array because arrays have a fixed size and you should be able to click as much as you want

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

With the above class when you click, rather than checking the entire grid, you have immediate access to the positions

First, use the class, so replace

```
final JButton nb = new JButton();
```

with

```
final JButton nb = new GridButton(x, y);
```

And in the action listener, access the values as well as add to a list

```
@Override 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    GridButton source = (GridButton) e.getSource();
    list.add(new int[] {source.x, source.y});
}
```

> changing the coordinates stored inside whenever a JButton is clicked

I'm not sure why you would do that, but you would have to modify both the button itself via setter methods on that class as well as swap/reset the Button array with the new positioning

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I see now that a list makes more sense than an array. I am getting an error however on the .add where eclipse tells me to change it to .addAll and if I do that it wants to change back to .add.

Comment: Are you sure you made the list use an integer array rather than just integers?

Comment: I believe so, isn't that this part: List<Integer[]>

Comment: Actually, should be `List<int[]>`